# vitePluginString is not a function

Tags: svelte, vite

Created a vite + svelte

```
$ npm init vite@latest
✔ Project name: … app1
✔ Select a framework: › svelte
✔ Select a variant: › svelte-ts
```

wanted to include [vite-plugin-string](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-plugin-string?activeTab=readme) to use `glsl` file

installed

`npm install --save-dev vite-plugin-string`

configured `vite.config.js` file as below

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import { svelte } from '@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte'
import vitePluginString from 'vite-plugin-string'


// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [svelte(),vitePluginString()]
})
```

As soon as run `npm run dev`

I get this error

```
> app1@0.0.0 dev
> vite

failed to load config from ....../Six/trailRun/vite.config.js
error when starting dev server:
TypeError: vitePluginString is not a function
    at file:///....../Six/trailRun/vite.config.js?t=1642958252054:8:22
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:195:25)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async ESMLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:337:24)
    at async importModuleDynamicallyWrapper (node:internal/vm/module:437:15)
    at async loadConfigFromFile (/....../Six/trailRun/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-f5552faa.js:75089:31)
    at async resolveConfig (/....../Six/trailRun/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-f5552faa.js:74656:28)
    at async createServer (/....../Six/trailRun/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-f5552faa.js:60326:20)
    at async CAC.<anonymous> (/....../Six/trailRun/node_modules/vite/dist/node/cli.js:688:24)
```

What changes I need to make to correct this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The module actually exports the plugin function in a `default` property:

```js
// vite.config.js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import { svelte } from '@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte'
import vitePluginString from 'vite-plugin-string'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    svelte(),
    vitePluginString.default(), 
  ],
})
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vite-plugin-string?file=vite.config.ts)

Comment: I have several Vite plugins where this seems to be a problem, yet they all document their usage as _not_ requiring the `.default`. There seems to be a problem at a deeper level, since it seems obvious that this is not the intended usage.

Comment: Perhaps it is supposed to be imported like this `import { plugin as vitePluginString } from 'vite-plugin-string'`